# Adding Items to Dictionary Property From Xaml File

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have added a Dictionary property named Xy in the user control I developed. The dictionary type is `Dictionary<int, string>`

While using the user control in a wpf application, I need to add these items to the dictionary from the xaml file of the application.

```
0,"a.bmp"
1,"b.bmp"
```

How can I do this?

The user control code is given below

```
public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
    {         
        private Dictionary<int, string> xy = new Dictionary<int, string>();

        public Dictionary<int, string> Xy
        {
            get
            {
                return xy;
            }
            set
            {
                xy = value;
            }
        }
    }
```

**Edit**
The basic idea is to add a set of value, image name pairs to the disctionary from the xaml file. Sample pairs are given below

0,"a.bmp"
 1,"b.bmp"

If value 0 is set some property, show image a.bmp
If value 1 is set some property, show image b.bmp

Is that possible?

Comment: So unclear.  Are you asking how to load the Dictionary or how to return the value from one item in the Dictionary?

Comment: @Blam: I want to Add item to the dictionary

Comment: I think your question is crystal clear, wonder why there are unrelated answers.

Answer (score 2):

This may work:

```
<u:UserControl1>
   <u:UserControl1.Xy>
      <sys:String x:Key="0">a.bmp</sys:String>
      <sys:String x:Key="1">b.bmp</sys:String>
   </u:UserControl1.Xy>
</u:UserControl1>
```

Not sure about the key conversion though, you may need to use something like `<x:Key><sys:Int32>0</sys:Int32></x:Key>` for that. But try the simpler approach first.